# re-inheritance static field from class and interface

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, interface, superclass

```
interface A {
    public static String name = "A";
}
interface B {
    public static String name = "B";
}
class X implements A { }
class Y extends X implements B { }
public void test_getField() {
    try {
        assertEquals(B.class.getField("name"), Y.class.getField("name"));
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        fail("Got exception");
    }
}
```

Why does `Y.class.getField("name")` return `B.name` instead of `A.name`?
Is there any answer in the Java specification?

Comment: Actually, now that I am writing my answer, I notice that you used reflection because the compilation of anything using `Y.name` would fail because it is ambiguous. It is a good catch but it can't be use correctly (without reflection).

Comment: btw you could accept an answer here... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

The direct superinterface will be searched before superclass, see the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField(java.lang.String)) of `getField`:

> The field to be reflected is determined by the algorithm that follows.
> Let C be the class represented by this object:
>
> If C declares a public field with the name specified, that is the
> field to be reflected.
>
> If no field was found in step 1 above, this
> algorithm is applied recursively to **each direct superinterface of C**.
> The direct superinterfaces are searched in the order they were
> declared.
>
> If no field was found in steps 1 and 2 above, and C has a
> superclass S, then this algorithm is invoked recursively upon S. If C
> has no superclass, then a NoSuchFieldException is thrown.

Comment: @user6690200 while you are correct, this is not the *entire* story https://stackoverflow.com/a/50059001/1059372

Answer (score 2):

The key point here is that you're using reflection and getting unexpected behavior.

Although you already have the reflection algorithm, I will add a visual example.

First of all, using normal access you will get:

```
class Y extends X implements B {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

> Error:(29, 36) java: reference to name is ambiguous   both variable
>   name in com.test.A and variable name in com.test.B match

Now considering an example:

```
class Y extends X implements A, B {}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        Y y = new Y();
        System.out.println("Y : " + y.getClass().getField("name"));
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Y : public static final java.lang.String A.name
```

Changing signature to

```
class Y extends X implements A, B {}
```

Gives us output:

```
Y : public static final java.lang.String B.name
```

> The direct superinterfaces are searched in the order they were
>   declared.

Further observation shows that actually we can get both names like:

```
class Y extends X implements A, B { }

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Y y = new Y();
        Field[] fields = Y.class.getFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            System.out.println(field.get(y));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A
B
```

And for both `class Y extends X implements B { }` and `class Y extends X implements B, A { }`:

```
B
A
```

The first `name` resolved in runtime comes from first implemented interface (direct superinterface) because it has higher precedence, then comes the value from the second interface, then the value from the superclass.

When you calling `Y.class.getField("name")` you're getting the first resolved `name` which comes from first direct superinterface - `A`.

Comment: @J-Alex what do you think this will print? `Arrays.stream(Y.class.getFields())
                .map(Field::getName)
                .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);`

Comment: @Eugene seems like we have 2 fields with the same name but different values, but when getting the field by the reflection we are getting the 'first' one from first superinterface. I'll adjust the answer.

Comment: @J-Alex that is the point, can you declare two fields with the same name in a file yourself?

Comment: @Eugene No, you can't. But they are not in the same file. They are resolved by reflection at runtime from different places.

Comment: @Eugene Added more info based on your observations.

Comment: @J-Alex I finally found some time to post an answer about this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50059001/1059372

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question. Let's first simplify this a bit

```
static class Parent {
    public int x = 1;
}

static class Child extends Parent {
    public int x = 2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Child c = new Child();
    Parent p = c;

    System.out.println(c.x);
    System.out.println(p.x);

}
```

What do you think this will print?

It will be `2 1`Instance variables are inherited, but they are not overridable. This is called hiding, Parent’s x is hidden by Child’s x. Instance variables are inherited, but they are not overridable. This is called hiding, Parent’s x is hidden by Child’s x.

The second line though… Where are we pulling x from? We do have a Parent reference, but it’s pointing to a Child instance, right? It’s like Child has two different variables with the same name; one it declares, one it inherits. Does it?

```
      Arrays.stream(Child.class.getFields())
            .map(Field::getName)
            .forEachOrdered(System.out::println); // x x
```

It’s like Child has two fully qualified variables and depending on the reference you can access one or the other.

Now to your example (a bit simplified):

```
interface First {
    int x = 3;
}

interface Second {
    int x = 4;
}

static class Impl implements First, Second {}
```

What do you think this will print?

```
Arrays.stream(Impl.class.getFields())
            .map(Field::getName)
            .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

As in the previous example, it will print x twice, the meaning of this is explained above.

---

Knowing this, let's go to your question (again, a bit simplified):

```
interface First {
    int x = 1;
}

interface Second {
    int x = 2;
}

class Impl implements First, Second {

}

Field left = First.class.getField("x");
// you might think that this will fail, since Impl has two variables x... 
Field right = Impl.class.getField("x");

if (!left.equals(right)) {
        throw new AssertionError("Aren't they equal?");
}
```

As the way this is written right now, this will NOT throw the `AssertionError`.

The idea here is that `Field#equals` uses 3 things for equality: `type`, `name` and `declaringClass`. The first two obviously match, so all we care about is the last one. And this is where the JLS comes at help [which the other answer has already provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49999370/1059372).

That is the reason btw, that if you change the order of interface declarations : `class Impl implements Second, First` that code will throw the AssertionError. Because now, x will be resolved from `Second` (in the order of the declaration... ), but we compare it with `First`.

Comment: this is helpful :)